# Split string from a regex in python re

Tags: python, regex

I have patterns like this:

```
" 1+2;\r\n\r(%o2) 3\r\n(%i3) "
```

i'd like to split them up into:

```
[" 1+2;","(%o2) 3","(%i3)"]
```

the regex for the first pattern is hard to construct since it could be anything a user asks of an algebra system, the second could be:

```
'\(%o\d+\).'
```

and the last something like this:

```
'\(%i\d+\)
```

im not stumped by the regex part strictly but how to actually split once i know the correct pattern. 
how would i split this?

Comment: You don't seem to just split but also do some replacement. Is that your will to have those added spaces ?

Comment: the spaces are not neccessary

Comment: Is that a coincidence or are you just splitting by line really ?

Comment: I think you want a parser, not a regex.

Comment: the pattern has lines yes, along the same places i need them, but this may not neccessarily be the case in al instances, this is just a coincidence iv made an edit

Comment: @MikeM see comment below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about splitting on `(\r|\n)+`?

Comment: looks right, but im trying to to bank on the new line characters, i'd like to use the (%o2), (%i3) king of patterns=> bracket+percent+letter+digit(s)+bracket

Comment: @MikeM, id like to keep that as part of the second "portion", sorry of i was unclear.

Comment: @mike Sorry, I'm not sure what do you mean by "bank on the new line characters" (I don't use English everyday and am still learning). Also by "king of patterns" you mean "kind of patterns"? Anyway if this answer doesn't entirely solve your problem there is no need to accept it.

Comment: i dont want to rely on the new line characters though in this case they work, but in a general case they might not be there, (i accepted because it answers the question i asked AS IS), @MikeM as the question stands it IS answered, what i wanted it seems should be extended to another question

Comment: If there are no new line characters which parts should be found? What data interest you? If you only want to *find* `bracket+percent+letter+digit(s)+bracket` then maybe use `\(%[io]\d+\)`. If there can be other letters just add them to `[]` like `[ioz]` or just use `[a-z]` for letters from `a` to `z`. You can even use this pattern to find first two `(%o2)`,`(%i3)` -> `(\(%o\d+\)).*?(\(%i\d+\))`. If you use this regex `(\(%o\d+\))` should be accessed as group 1 and `(\(%i\d+\))` as group 2.

Answer (score 1):

Will this code work for you?

```
patterns = [p.strip() for x in " 1+2;\r\n\r(%o2) 3\r\n(%i3) ".split("\r\n")]
```

To clarify:

```
>>> patterns = " 1+2;\r\n\r(%o2) 3\r\n(%i3) ".split("\r\n")
>>> patterns
[' 1+2;', '\r(%o2) 3', '(%i3) ']
>>> patterns = [p.strip() for p in patterns]
['1+2;', '(%o2) 3', '(%i3)']
```

This way you split the lines and get rid from unnecessary white characters.

EDIT: also: Python String has also splitlines() method:

```
splitlines(...)
    S.splitlines([keepends]) -> list of strings

    Return a list of the lines in S, breaking at line boundaries.
    Line breaks are not included in the resulting list unless keepends
    is given and true.
```

So this code may be changed to:

```
patterns = [p.strip() for x in " 1+2;\r\n\r(%o2) 3\r\n(%i3) ".splitlines()]
```

This may possibly answer the problem with NL's without CR's and all different combinations.

Comment: works for this case, but i could get caught when there are no carriage returns,  see the comment on Pshemo's answer

Comment: I edited my answer to include splitlines() example, you might want to check it out. I believe that standard method should handle new lines without carriage returns pretty ok.